# How do I specify the type for `map` in `IntoIterator` impl?

Tags: generics, rust

I have the following code:

```
struct Container<T>(T);

struct MyStruct<T> {
    entries: Vec<T>,
}

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a MyStruct<Container<T>> {
    type Item = &'a Container<T>;
    type IntoIter = std::slice::Iter<'a, Container<T>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        let entries = &self.entries;
        entries.into_iter()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_struct: MyStruct<Container<usize>> = MyStruct {
        entries: vec![
            Container(0),
            Container(1),
            Container(2),
            Container(3),
            Container(4),
        ],
    };
    
    for c in my_struct.into_iter() {
        println!("{}", c.0);
        // I want c to be usize not Container<usize>.
        println!("{}", c); 
    }
}
```

I would like the iterator obtained from `into_iter()` to produce the inner value of `Container`.

I tried like this:

```
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a MyStruct<Container<T>> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = std::slice::Iter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        let entries = &self.entries;
        
        // Map to the inner value.
        entries.into_iter().map(|c| c.0)
    }
}
```

But it doesn't compile with the error below:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:25:9
   |
21 |     fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
   |                           -------------- expected `std::slice::Iter<'_, T>` because of return type
...
25 |         entries.into_iter().map(|c| c.0)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::slice::Iter`, found struct `Map`
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::slice::Iter<'_, T>`
              found struct `Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, Container<T>>, [closure@src/main.rs:25:33: 25:40]>`
```

If I follow the suggestions I get more and more complicated errors.

[Rust playground code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=474a3d4b63d4a77cdc57d0c87a91419c)

Comment: Specify the closure as fn pointer or just return a boxed iterator.

Comment: ^ That, or make your own mapping iterator, which removes the need for a closure/fnpointer. It works to use utilities like `.map()` in contexts where you can return `impl Iterator`, but it doesn't work so well in contexts that need a named type, like associated types.

Comment: Is there some way of using `PhantomData` in `MyStruct` to allow me to `impl Iterator`? Otherwise how would I create my own mapping iterator in this context or specify the closure as a function pointer? I don't want to use the heap with a boxed iterator if I can help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```rust
struct Container<T>(T);

struct MyStruct<T> {
    entries: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> IntoIterator for MyStruct<Container<T>> {
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = std::iter::Map<std::vec::IntoIter<Container<T>>, fn(Container<T>) -> T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.entries.into_iter().map(|c| c.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_struct: MyStruct<Container<usize>> = MyStruct {
        entries: vec![Container(0), Container(1), Container(2), Container(3)],
    };

    for c in my_struct.into_iter() {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was not aware that you could use `fn(Container<T>)` in this situation. I had been trying the function traits `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce`.

Comment: @Dan, when your closure does not capture any variables, it can be coerced to a function pointer.

Answer (score -1):

You could implement Deref instead, and then you would only need to add some stars (*) to deref enough:

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

struct Container<T>(T);

impl<T> Deref for Container<T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

struct MyStruct<T> {
    entries: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> Deref for MyStruct<T> {
    type Target = Vec<T>;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.entries
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_struct: MyStruct<Container<usize>> = MyStruct {
        entries: vec![Container(0), Container(1), Container(2), Container(3)],
    };

    for c in my_struct.iter() {
        println!("{}", c.0);
        println!("{}", **c);
    }
}
```

Comment: My example is a simplistic one. In reality the `Container` struct is in a separate crate that I don't have access to modify so wouldn't be able to implement `Deref`.